# Decision trees for Rstudio v3.3

Tags: r, decision-trees

Anyone know the best packages to build a decision tree in Rstudio v3.3?

I want to look at some data-driven segmentation for my data. I was thinking of doing chaid analysis (mainly because this is why I've done in the past).

I've looked around myself, but can't find the best package for this version!

Comment: Which packages have you looked at? What did you not like about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" package depends on your goals and data really.

A few tree / forest packages that I've come across:

1. `randomForest` - an implementation of the original algorithm
2. `ranger` - a flexible implementation designed to run on high-dimensional data (my personal favourite forest package)
3. `party`'s ctree / cforest functions - conditional inference trees / forests
4. `rpart`

Some of these packages focus on forests rather than trees; you can coerce the forest algorithm into building a tree by flexing appropriate parameters.